# Как убрать кавычки из результата?

Tags: python

Как убрать кавычки из результата?

Мой код :

```
a ={x[:x.find(':')]: x[x.find(':')+1:]for x in input().split()}
```

Ответ должен выглядеть так:

```
{73: 'yjanlou', 82: 'fsbohtg', 58: 'xfuln', 1: 'zshywk'}
```

А у меня получается так:

```
{'73': 'yjanlou', '82': 'fsbohtg', '58': 'xfuln', '1': 'zshywk'}
```

Comment: Нужно для ключа сделать int(), сейчас это строка

Answer (score 3):

```
print({int(x[:x.find(':')]): x[x.find(':')+1:]for x in input().split()})
```

ввод:

```
In: 1:one 2:two 3:tree
```

вывод:

```
Out: {1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'tree'}
```

Comment: Элеганто: в одну строчку :)

Comment: @Victor так код автора и был в одну строчку))

Comment: Зато этот работает как надо )))

Comment: @Victor это главное)

Comment: Хорошо хотя не: <q>))))</q>

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае можно воспользоваться регулярными выражениями:

```
import re

a = dict(map(lambda x: (int(x[0]), x[1]), re.findall(r"(\d+)\s*:\s*(\w+)", s)))
```

---

результат:

```
print(a)
# {73: 'yjanlou', 82: 'fsbohtg', 58: 'xfuln', 1: 'zshywk'}
```